# Delay Differential Equations System of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, delay-differential-equations

I need some help with

1. Confirmation my system of equations truly is a DDE system and
2. Any insight into users who have solved state dependent DDE systems (either using matlab ddesd or could recommend a scheme maybe like a modified RK ect)

Find below my system of equations - typical Newton Euler representation of a single rigid body.  In my implementation I simply solved for the derivatives in each equation to form a system of ODE's and use matlab ode45 for constant force and moment terms.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
        F_x &= m \left(\dot{u} + \omega_{y_{\bar{B}}} w - \omega_{z_{\bar{B}}} v \right) \\   
        F_y &= m \left(\dot{v} + \omega_{z_{\bar{B}}} u - \omega_{x_{\bar{B}}} w \right) \\
        F_z &= m \left(\dot{w} + \omega_{x_{\bar{B}}} v - \omega_{y_{\bar{B}}} u \right) \\
        u &= \left(\dot{x}_{\bar{B}} + \omega_{y_{\bar{B}}} z_{\bar{B}} - \omega_{z_{\bar{B}}} y_{\bar{B}}\right) \\
        v &= \left(\dot{y}_{\bar{B}} + \omega_{z_{\bar{B}}} x_{\bar{B}} - \omega_{x_{\bar{B}}} z_{\bar{B}}\right) \\
        w &= \left(\dot{z}_{\bar{B}} + \omega_{x_{\bar{B}}} y_{\bar{B}} - \omega_{y_{\bar{B}}} x_{\bar{B}}\right) \\
        M_x &= I_{B_{xx}}\dot{\omega}_x - \left(I_{B_{yy}} - I_{B_{zz}}\right)\omega_y\omega_z  \\   
        M_y &= I_{B_{yy}}\dot{\omega}_y - \left(I_{B_{zz}} - I_{B_{xx}}\right)\omega_z\omega_x  \\
        M_z &= I_{B_{zz}}\dot{\omega}_z - \left(I_{B_{xx}} - I_{B_{yy}}\right)\omega_x\omega_y  \\ 
        \omega_{x_{\bar{B}}} &= \dot{\phi} -\dot{\psi}\sin{\theta}\\
        \omega_{y_{\bar{B}}} &= \dot{\theta}\cos{\phi} + \dot{\psi}\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}\\
        \omega_{z_{\bar{B}}} &= \dot{\psi}\cos{\phi}\cos{\theta} - \dot{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

My next iteration of the problem is using non-constant force $F_x, F_y, F_z$ and moment $M_x, M_y, M_z$ terms that are dependent on the previous state.
I believe this makes the set of equations DDE is this correct?

I've tried to implement this in matlab using ddesd and have done so incorrectly because my history function is overwriting (if I zero out my force and moment terms for debugging) or acting as a multiplicative factor to the returned values from my delay functions. I've already posted on Matlabs forums with not much success yet. Any suggestions, pointers? Thank you.

Comment: The equations you have are currently ODEs. If you introduce terms that are the state but with a constant delay i.e. $\omega(t - \epsilon)$ then yes it is a DDE. but, is that what you mean by "previous state"? Can you clarify? Because a "previous state" isn't necessarily modelled by ideal delays. More precision is required there.

Comment: Yes!  So my intent is that say $F_x$ at time t would be a function of the previous solution of these equations at (t - dt).  The time step could be constant so constant delay.  I'm a little fuzzy on time dependent delay versus state dependent delay.  Really this is an IVP and at each solution (I'm referring to as step) I need the initial conditions (or previous solution) to calculate the force and moment terms.  Does that provide more clarity?